# Particle moving on ellpse with foci as origin

Tags: homework-and-exercises, celestial-mechanics

I'm reading the book "An introduction to Celestial Mechanics" by Forest Ray Moulton. In the first chapter, I got stuck on the following problem:

> A particle moves in the ellipse whose parameter and eccentricity are $p$ and $e$ with uniform angular speed with respect to one of the foci as origin; Find the components of velocity and acceleration along and perpendicular to the radius vector and parallel to the $x$ and $y$-axes in terms of the radius vector and the time.

After struggling some time with it I looked at the first line of the answer to get some help. He starts it with 
$$v_r=\frac{ec}{p}\cdot r^2sin(ct), \quad \theta=ct$$
which puzzled me. I tried starting with the following relation
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=c_1=constant\Rightarrow \theta=c_1t+c_2$$
but could not advance any further...

My question is: What is a good approach to derive the position vector when the origin is on one of the foci? Any help is appreciated.

PS: What the hell is a "parameter" of an ellipse? Never heard of it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the following polar-coordinates equation for an ellipse with focus at the origin:

$$r=\frac{p}{1+e\cos\theta}.$$

Note: The parameter $p$ is often written in terms of the semi-major axis $a$ and the eccentricity $e$ as $p=a(1-e^2)$. Another name for $p$ is the *semi-latus rectum*.

Differentiate to find Moulton’s expression for $v_r=\dot r$, and take it from there.

Comment: nice! could you point me to a link with the demonstration of that relation for $r$ please? thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_forms for the form with $a$ instead of $p$. See http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap3/Chap3-2/part4.htm for a discussion that calls $p$ the “parameter”.

Comment: Sometimes you see the cosine in the denominator with a minus sign. It depends on whether you choose the zero angle to be at closest approach or at farthest approach. I chose the form that gives Moulton’s radial velocity, assuming I got my signs right when I differentiated.